# useState is not updating the state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

`ChangeHandler` updates the state fine.

However, updating the state of `id` on `onSubmit` does not seem to update the id.

**Code is**:

```js
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Form(props) {
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
        name: "",
        url: "",
        id: ""
    })

    const ChangeHandler = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target

        setUserInput((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                [name]: value
            }
        })
    }

    const clearForm = () => {
        setUserInput({
            name: "",
            url: "",
            id: ""
        })
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        setUserInput(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) 
            } //does not work?
        });

        props.onFormData(userInput)
        clearForm()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input name="name" className="input" type="text" value={userInput.name} placeholder="Name" onChange={ChangeHandler}></input>
                <input name="url" className="input" type="text" value={userInput.url} placeholder="url" onChange={ChangeHandler}></input>
                <button type="submit" className="button is-primary" >Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You call `clearForm()` right after the fact which clears the `id` again, if you mean state in this view. If you mean the state in the `props.onFormData()` call, that will not have updated yet.

Comment: @Etheryte removing clearForm does not have any impact on the id though. it is still empty :( How do i make sure it updates? It seems dirty to useEffect for something this basic?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `setUserInput`. Just sand parms like this:

```js
props.onFormData({
  ...userInput,
  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
})
```

When use change state, the state will applies on next render. That's why you can't use updated state.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
setUserInput((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
  };
});
props.onFormData(userInput);
```

`userInput` will not have updated to the new value you set yet. The new value will be available on the next render, until then `userInput` will still give you the old value. If it helps, you can think of `setUserInput()` as a deferred function that will resolve the update later.

You can sidestep the problem by putting your new state in a temporary variable which you can use for both purposes.

```
const newUserInput = {
  ...userInput,
  id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
};
setUserInput(newUserInput);
props.onFormData(newUserInput);
```